# Setup Apache in Amazon AWS

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I tried to setup apache 2.2 in amazon aws using amazon ami. i did installed httpd and php and congirue http.conf to use /var/www/html.

Then put file index.html on that folder. But when i tried to use browser to browse my domain which is ec2-122-248-255-181.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com, nothing was loaded.

I did start httpd by running apachectl start, and i can see it listening on port 80.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that you are allowing traffic on port 80 in your EC2 security group.

Go to your EC2 dashboard and click on Security Groups.
Select the Security Group that is attached to your instance. 
Check that there is a line that says

```
HTTP        tcp        80       80        0.0.0.0/0
```

If it exists then your problem lies elsewhere otherwise add the line using the select boxes.

Comment: Yeah, you rock.

Answer (score 1):

Might also be worth allowing HTTPS on port 443 as well:

```
HTTP        tcp        443       443        0.0.0.0/0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect locally? SSH into the instance and try to `telnet 127.0.0.1 80`.

If you can't, check for a firewall locally on the machine. Check the system logs, and the apache error logs.

If you can, check your Security Group in EC2 and make sure port 80 is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of your html files as well.