# Nginx won't listen to 443 even when netstat says it does

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I installed SSL on a server, it all went well as I did on other servers before, but this is just not working, I check with **sudo netstat -t -l -p -n**  and I get this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1062/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2560/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3129/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3129/nginx
```

But when I try to access the website, the connection times out, now if I check with https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ for port 443, it will say the port is closed. Nginx -t returns no errors.

sudo iptables -L shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

sudo ufw status shows:

```
Status: inactive
```

My default.vhost file:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    # listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /jet/app/www/website/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /jet/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.inc;

#location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
#    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }

}


server {
    listen       443 default_server;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /jet/etc/nginx/SSL/website.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /jet/etc/nginx/SSL/private/website.key;


    server_name  _;
    root         /jet/app/www/website/public;




    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /jet/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.inc;

#location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
#    }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }




}
```

Wth could be going on?

Comment: firewall rules?

Comment: edited with more info

Comment: are you sure the ip you are checking the port 443 on from online test is on the server? can you do curl -ISL https://yoursite from server itself, what message do you get?

Comment: just did, it times out

Comment: did you check the ip, does it show in ipadresses on the server, can you ping it from the server? do other ports on that IP work, can you curl -ISL https://localhost, is the vhost for site wildcard or on IP?

Comment: edit: added my default.vhost
curl -ISL localhost returns 200, but I think it calls on port 80. curl -ISL localhost:443 returns error 400

Comment: add https:// before localhost, it displays it at link in comments and doesn't show https part

Comment: curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

Comment: I think it's because localhost is not my domain name?

Comment: Edit /etc/hosts to include your domain name with the server IP address, then do the curl.

Comment: if you are hosting this server in a webhosting such as aws/azure etc they have firewalls beyond the host itself. you have to enable 443 from those as well

Comment: what is your hosting ? port is closed means it must be firewalled. still.. not necessarily the os firewall

Comment: It is an EC2 instance on AWS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679227/how-can-i-open-port-2195-and-443-on-my-amazon-ec2-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309910/https-setup-in-amazon-ec2

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: You nailed it sir.

Answer (score 1):

Go to EC2 dashboard and click on Security Groups. Select the Security Group that is relevant to your instance
and add below line

```
HTTP        tcp        443       443        0.0.0.0/0
```

source : 
[Setup Apache in Amazon AWS](https://serverfault.com/questions/244514/setup-apache-in-amazon-aws/244521#244521)